How can I create viewpager without view pager
I want to make my fragment transition like viewpager but I don't want to use viewpager cuz if i use it i have to use certaim amount of fragments in adapter.
And also i want fragment transition like viewpager when bottom navigation bar button clicked.Thanks guys for answer I provided the reason of why I want that below)
I am developing an app and the main activity of this app has 3 main fargments and there is a bottom navigation bar on the bottom. When you press one BNB fragments change like viewpager. And also you can change fragments with swipe. And when you press a button in one of fragments. Fragment appears also in the main activity. In this app there is only one activity. Cuz if there was a second activity, the changig of fragments should be slower but it is faster. The problem if we use view pager in main activity we can't use other fragments except which are we give in adapter, so we need sexond activity to show other fragments. So I think they made it without viewpager, and I also want to make it view pager. Here is the link of the app you can check it out https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uz.islom
I have no idea what to try

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
